# How to mock a function which does not return anything in java

Tags: java, junit, mockito, java-7, powermock

```
public class Service1 {

private Service2 service2;

// FunctionA
private FuncA(Object1 obj1) {

    /*
    code to make Obj2 from Obj1
    */

    service2.FuncB(obj2);
  }

}

public class Service2 {
  // FunctionB
  private FuncB(Object2 obj) {
    obj.field=value;  
  }

}
```

I am trying to write Unit Test Case for Func A (as mentioned above) and for that need to mock Func B(as mentioned above).
Pls. help how can I do that in Java 7.

Ps. Newbie to Java

Comment: i guess the code you are providing doesn't compile

Comment: Func . what it is?

Comment: Welcome to So. Please write the question assuming that what is clear to you, may not be clear to others. What is UT ? Where is `Func` defined ?

Comment: @c0der Can you pls. see the Sample code too. Func is Function and clearly specified.

Comment: @ankitagupta your code is either not Java or incomplete. If it was Java `Func` would be the return type of the function `B` in your `Service2` class. But as you are calling `service2.funcB(...)` in your code, there is some mismatch....

Comment: "Func is Function and clearly specified." - Not in the snippet you gave us. As is, function B in Service2 class is never called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `service2` member in your `Service1` class, that you are going to test, to a mock object created by your mocking framework. This could look something like this:

```
public class Service1Test {

    @Mock
    private Service2 service2;

    @InjectMocks // service2 mock will be injected into service1
    private Service1 service1;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void doTest() {

        Object someObject = null; // create object matching your needs
        service1.FuncA(someObject);

        Object someOtherObj = null; // create object matching your needs
        verify(service2, times(1)).FuncB(someOtherObj);

        // perform additional assertions
    }
}
```